# Come insegnare italiano

Tags: resources

Ciao a tutti, 
un'amica australiana mi ha chiesto di darle qualche lezione di italiano una volta alla settimana. 
Lei ha già seguito dei corsi di Italiano e penso sia di livello intermedio. 
Non avendo molta esperienza in materia di insegnamento, potreste consigliarmi qualche attività o lettura interessante da cui partire per impostare una breve e informale lezione? 
Ogni consiglio è ben accetto, grazie.

Comment: Benvenuta! Il sito tratta di questioni specifiche della lingua italiana e questa domanda sembra un po' troppo generica e aperta a opinioni diverse.

Comment: Potresti cercare in qualche bancarella o liberia dell'usato per dei testi di italiano della scuola media; oppure libri di letteratura per ragazzi e invitare la tua amica a leggerli ad alta voce. Consiglio anche la visione di qualche vecchio film o sceneggiato Rai (questi si trovano anche su Youtube)

Answer (score 3):

Grazie a tutti per le risposte. 
Alla fine ho trovato molte risorse online che mi hanno aiutato a preparare la prima lezione. 
Loescher ha ottime schede di grammatica scaricabili gratuitamente [1](http://italianoperstranieri.loescher.it/archivio-di-grammatica.n445)

Altri siti offrono degli spunti per preparare delle lezioni con esercizi. 
[2](http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/italiano/corso_di_italiano_intermedio.htm)

Ho aggiunto i link in caso vogliate dare un'occhiata.